# norm inequaity for A-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

If the matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is symmetric and positive definite then we can define the improduct
$$(x,y)_A = x^T A y$$
and the related $A$-norm
$$\left \| x \right \|_A = \sqrt{(x,x)_A} = \sqrt{x^T A x}$$
I guess we can also define the norm of a matrix $X \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ as
$$\left \| X \right \|_A = \sup \left\{{\frac {\|Xx\|_A}{\|x\|_A}}:x\in \mathbb{R}^{n}{\text{ with }}x\neq 0\right\}$$
On the wikipediapage https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm there is a written that in some cases, it holds that 
$$\|AB\| \le \|A\|\|B\| $$
My question: Does this also holds for the $A$-norm that I defined?

kind regards
Koen

Comment: By the way, it should be $\| x \|_A = (x^T A x)^{1/2}$.

Comment: I edited it, thanks for the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It holds in even higher generality: If $A \in \mathbb R^{m \times k}$ and $B \in \mathbb R^{k \times n}$, then $AB \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and we have the inequality $$ ||AB|| \leq ||A|| \cdot ||B||.$$ 
To see this, it suffices to show that for any vector $x \in \mathbb R^n$ with $x \neq 0$ the inequality $$\frac {||ABx||}{||x||} \leq ||A|| \cdot ||B||$$ holds. If $Bx = 0 \in \mathbb R^k$, then the left-hand side is zero and the inequality certainly holds. If $Bx \neq 0$, then we can do the following trick $$\frac {||ABx||}{||x||} = \frac {||ABx||}{||Bx||} \cdot \frac{||Bx||}{||x||} \leq ||A|| \cdot ||B||.$$

In fact, the same trick works on *bounded* endomorphisms between not necessarily finite dimensional **Banach spaces**.

Comment: $Bx$ is in $\mathbb{R}^k$ instead of in $ \mathbb{R}^m$

Comment: Thanks, mixed up the indices. Everything should be right now.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does hold for your norm. In fact all operator norms are submultiplicative. It is simple to see this:  $\| AB x \| \leq \| A \| \| Bx \| \leq \| A \| \| B \| \| x \|$ for all $x$. Now use the definition of operator norm to see that the inequality holds (note that the definition of $\|\cdot\|_A$ that you used is exactly how an operator norm is defined in a more general setting).